# How to identify an android device uniquely

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile, expo

Which method can we use to uniquely identify an Android device for its lifetime or until the phone is reset

I tried using android_id but it remains constant for lifetime if the android version is lower than 8. but in higher versions it changes from app to app.

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 0):

I use this util class to get the device id for android

```
object AppConstants {

    @JvmStatic
    fun getDeviceId(context: Context): String {
       return Settings.Secure.getString(
          context.contentResolver,
          Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
      )
    }
}
```

To get the device id, use the following line of code

```
AppConstants.getDeviceId(this)
```

It works for me. It will never change the device id value.